# GoogleMap карта не отображается

Tags: flutter, dart

Если в ручном режиме задать координаты

```
target: LatLng(48.5244722, 39.2643343),
```

, то карта отображается. Если координаты определять динамически, с помощью **package:geolocator** карта не отображается. **ПОЧЕМУ?** Далее, полный пример кода и скриншот.

***main.dart***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: MyHomePage(),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 String _str = ''; //для проверки
 double _latitude = 0.0;  //широта
 double _longitude = 0.0; //долгота

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _getPosition().then((value) {
   _latitude = value.latitude;
   _longitude = value.longitude;
   _str = '$_latitude\n$_longitude';
  });
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();

 }

 void _f1() {
  setState(() {

  });
 }

 Future<Position> _getPosition() async {
  Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);
  return position;
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
   children: [
    GoogleMap(
     initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
      //target: LatLng(48.5244722, 39.2643343),
      target: LatLng(_latitude, _longitude),
      zoom: 19.151926040649414,
      bearing: 222.8334901395799,
     ),
     mapType: MapType.hybrid,
    ),
    Align(
     alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.95),
     child: Text(
      _str,
      style: TextStyle(
       fontSize: 20.0,
      ),
     ),
    ),
   ],
  );
 }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что надо работать через `GoogleMapController` из метода `onMapCreated`

Comment: Уважаемый MiT, огромное Вам спасибо, почти все получилось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Перенос ответа из комментариев, чтобы закрыть вопрос.*

В виджете `GoogleMap` есть метод `onMapCreated`, у которого в параметре передается `GoogleMapController`. Через `GoogleMapController` следует управлять картой.

Пример:

```
class MapSample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MapSample> createState() => MapSampleState();
}

class MapSampleState extends State<MapSample> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
          zoom: 14.4746,
        ),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: _goToTheLake,
        label: Text('To the lake!'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.directions_boat),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _goToTheLake() async {
    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(
          bearing: 192.8334901395799,
          target: LatLng(37.43296265331129, -122.08832357078792),
          tilt: 59.440717697143555,
          zoom: 19.151926040649414,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```